# Duplicate file channel in Java

Tags: java, file, io, jvm

We can open a channel as simple as `Files.newByteChannel(path)` and that would work fine. The problem is if I want to open more then one channel:

```
Channel chan1 = Files.newByteChannel(path);
Channel chan2 = Files.newByteChannel(path);
```

The example above does not work well in general. Consider the circumstance:

```
Channel chan1 = Files.newByteChannel(path); //OK
//Some other process moved path and created an new file with the path
Channel chan2 = Files.newByteChannel(path); //Damn!
```

The race condition occurs. In linux we have [`dup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html)-like syscalls as well as [`fcntl(F_DUPFD, int)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html)

```
int fd == open(path);
int duplicated = fcntl(fd, F_DUPFD, fd);
```

and that should work.

Is there a way to do this in Java and avoid writing `JNI` function?

UPD: The reason I want the duplicate is that I want to transfer data from one file to multiple `SocketChannel`s concurrently. So it seems reasonable to have a separate `FileChannel` to transfer to a single `SocketChannel`.

Comment: Why? Why can't you just use the same `FileChannel` in two places?

Comment: @user207421 I want to transfer the same file into multiple storages (`SocketChannel`) concurrently. So it seems reasonable to have a separate `Channel` for each such "Pipe".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has no public API for duplicating FileChannels.

However, there is no need to duplicate FileChannel for writing to multiple SocketChannels concurrently.

1. [`FileChannel.transferTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo(long,long,java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel)) can be used concurrently in multiple threads (at least on Unix-like systems). As Javadoc says, this method does not modify channel's position.
2. [`FileChannel.read(ByteBuffer, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer,long)) can also be used concurrently on Unix. On Windows this method holds channel's position lock.
3. Alternatively it's possible to create multiple ByteBuffer views of the same FileChannel using [`FileChannel.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,long,long)). These MappedByteBuffers can be used concurrently.

If you still want to call `dup` from Java (though I wouldn't recommend doing this), you can abuse private API using Reflection:

- `int sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.dup(int fd)` is direct Java wrapper for `dup` on Unix;
- `long sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.duplicateHandle(long handle)` is Java wrapper for `DuplicateHandle` on Windows.

Comment: May I ask you the reason you would recommend against `dup`ing explicitly? To me it seems that using reflection to access internal API also makes the program non-portable.

Comment: @SomeName It's is more about using private API rather than `dup` itself. This approch is rather fragile and may not reliably work on all platforms / JDK versions.

Comment: Good answer. In my case I needed to read all available bytes written to an existing file channel starting from the beginning. FileChannel.read(ByteBuffer, long) was a great answer, as long as I managed the thread safety on the written bytes and write position.